# Arbitrage opportunity interview question

Tags: options, arbitrage, european-options

I have seen this interview question mentioned in a couple of places:

**There are three call options on the market, with the same expiry and with strikes 10, 20, and 30. Suppose the call option with strike 10 costs \$12, the call option with strike 20 costs \$7, and the call option with strike 30 costs \$1. Is there an arbitrage opportunity?**

The answer apparently is to buy two of the call options priced at \$20, and sell one of each of the call options priced at \$10 and \$30.

How does one arrive at this answer and is it unique?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A similar question for put option has been discussed in this question: [Finding Arbitrage in two Puts](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/20771/finding-arbitrage-in-two-puts/20773#20773). Basically, the call option payoff is a convex function of the strike. Then the call option price is also a convex function of the strike. Specifically, let $C(K)$ denote the call option price with strike $K$. Then for $ 0 < K_1 < K_2$, 
\begin{align*}
C\left(\frac{K_1 + K_2}{2}\right) \le \frac{1}{2}\big(C(K_1) + C(K_2) \big).
\end{align*}

For the example, let $K_1 = 10$ and $K_2 = 30$. Then
\begin{align*}
C(20) &= C\left(\frac{K_1 + K_2}{2}\right)\\
&\le \frac{1}{2}\big(C(K_1) + C(K_2) \big)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} (12 + 1) = 6.5.
\end{align*}
However, $C(20) = 7$, which contradicts to the above. Therefore, there is an arbitrage opportunity.

For an arbitrage strategy, we should short (i.e., sell) the option that is over-priced, and long (i.e., buy) the option that is under-priced. 
Specifically, we short two options with strike 20, and long one option with strike 10 and long another option with strike 30. At the start, we have the profit
\begin{align*}
2 \times 7 - 12 - 1 = 1 $.
\end{align*}
At the option maturity, the payoff to us is
\begin{align*}
(S_T-10)^+ + (S_T-30)^+ - 2 (S_T-20)^+ = 
\begin{cases}
 0, & \mbox{if } S_T \leq 10,\\
S_T-10, & \mbox{if } 10 \le S_T \le 20, \\
30-S_T, & \mbox{if } 20\le S_T \le 30,\\
0 , & \mbox{if } S_T \ge 30,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
which is always non-negative. Then, we have a guaranteed profit at the start and potential further profit at the option maturity, while without any liabilities.

Comment: Question about the payoff at maturity. Why is the payoff 0 when S_T is greater than 30? I thought that since we have the option to buy at 30, we would make money if the stock price is greater than 30.

Comment: If $S_T$ above 30 You make on the K=30 and the K=10, but you lose on the two K=20 that you are short. So you gain nothing.