# Arbitrage strategy one-period model

Tags: arbitrage

Consider a one-period model with a stock $S_0=1$ and $S_1>0$. Introduce call options with strikes $K_1<K_2<K_3$ maturing at $T=1$. Assume further that
$$
C(K_2)>\frac12(C(K_1)+C(K_3))
$$
and $K_2=\frac12(K_1+K_3)$. Here, $C(K_i)$ is the initial price of the call option with strike $K_i$. I want to find an explicit arbitrage strategy.

Comment: What have you tried to find an arbitrage?

Comment: Have a look of [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22328/arbitrage-opportunity-interview-question/22329#22329).